# Chartjs to display graph with csv

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x

I was getting a weird error while trying to plot a graph with chartjs in my django template.
I was following the document for chartjs but the graphs had a error for CORS blocked. Please help me out on how to get the csv or excel locally for my chart?

home.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/xlsx@0.14.3/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
      type: 'line',
      plugins: [ChartDataSource],
      options: {
        plugins: {
          datasource: {
            url: 'sample-dataset.xlsx'
          }
        }
      },
      data: {
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(19, 82, 150)',
            borderColor: 'transparent'
          },
          {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(196, 230, 255)',
            borderColor: 'transparent'
          }
        ]
      }
    });


</script>
</body>
```

Also there is another error in browser popping up as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined
```

What does that mean?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I moved to different solution. I would be happy to learn if you have something for the above problem :)

Comment: Thanks, @AnkurParanjpe.  What solution did you move to?  I ask out of curiosity.  I am quite a novice at chartjs (started learning only 3 days ago)

Comment: I moved to Django charts. Try these links... Django charts: http://www.fusioncharts.com/django-charts/. I also found graphos easy to understand as well. Django graphos: https://pypi.org/project/django-graphos/.